# Local variable referenced before assignment in async function, global variable of same name already assigned

Tags: python, asynchronous, global-variables, discord

I've been developing a Discord bot over the past few days. All was well until I encountered this problem:

```py
said_yes = False
said_no = False

@discordclient.event
async def on_ready():
    . . .   
    @discordclient.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == '.blackjack':
            . . .
        if message.content.lower() == 'yes' and said_no == False:
            said_yes = True;
            . . .
        elif message.content.lower() == 'no' and said_yes == False:
            said_no = True;
            . . .
        elif message.content.lower() != '.blackjack' and said_yes == False and said_no == False:
            . . .
```

The error message is:

```
File "filename.py", line 95, in on_message
    elif message.content.lower() == 'no' and said_yes == False:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'said_yes' referenced before assignment
```

**This error occurs on the second `if` statement and the first AND second `elif` statements.** The only difference is the variable (`said_yes` or `said_no`).

How can I fix this error? I expected the `said_yes` and `said_no` variables to be in the global scope.